# Excel 2013 Maximum Number of Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I understand that Excel 2013 has a limit of 1,048,576 rows (according to Microsoft). Is there a command that returns a Boolean value if the maximum number of rows has been reached? I am making a code that outputs data one row at a time to a worksheet and it may very well exceed the max row limit.

Comment: `Rows.Count` will return either 1,048,576 or 65,536 depending on the compatibility level of the worksheet it refers to. It shouldn't be too difficult to check if any cell in the bottom row (e.g. `IsEmpty(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1))`) is populated.

Comment: It might also be helpful to build in a counter variable into the output file/code. This way, you can preemptively add worksheets/switch to a worksheet once the limit has been reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach you could combine with the suggestions is to use

```
ActiveWorkbook.Excel8CompatibilityMode
```

If this returns true, the active workbook is running on Excel 2003 or prior compatibility mode and limited to 65,536 rows. If false you have 1,048,576 rows available. Example air code:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Excel8CompatibilityMode = False Then maxrows = 1048576 Else maxrows = 65536
```

Then check your output row against maxrows when writing to the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

```
bEndOfSheet = (counter = Sheet1.Rows.Count)
```

Comment: perfect way to do it